# Как убрать нули после запятой в определенных столбцах (float64 -> int)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Мой код:

```
df_CG1=pd.read_csv('payments_CG1.csv' ,sep=';')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df_CG1=df_CG1.dropna(how= 'all')
df_CG1
```

[image: датафрейм]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как столбцам: `user_id`, `revenue`, и `payment_service_id` присвоить "целые" значения, чтобы выглядило красиво.

Comment: Цитата из удалённого эпилога вопроса: _просьба не кидать помидорами_, всё таки кину, не надо текстовую информацию публиковать как какртинку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_CG1['user_id'] = df_CG1['user_id'].astype(int)
```

Остальные столбцы так же.

Comment: Спасибо большое ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы получаете тип данных `float64`, потому, что в некоторых строках у вас встречаются `NaN` значения, а целые типы в Numpy не понимают `NaN` и поэтому Pandas автоматически конвертирует такие столбцы в тип данных `float64`.

В современных версиях Pandas ввели новый тип данных `"Int64"` (с большой буквы), который понимает значения `NaN`.

Пример:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [np.nan, 3, np.nan]], columns=list("abc"))

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     a  b    c
0  1.0  2  3.0
1  NaN  3  NaN

In [17]: cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq("float64")]

In [18]: df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
...
```

решение:

```
In [19]: df[cols] = df[cols].astype("Int64")

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
      a  b     c
0     1  2     3
1  <NA>  3  <NA>

In [21]: df.dtypes
Out[21]:
a    Int64
b    int64
c    Int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Я сначала тоже про `float` стал писать, а потом смотрю - там все `NA` из датафрейма дропнуты не глядя ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, да я тоже это позже заметил, но потом подумал, что мой ответ сможет помочь другим, попавшим сюда из поисковиков )